# SQL Server 2008 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure, and inside I have a query for paging, which returns me a set of results depending on which page I am.

I have

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE()... then INSERT INTO @Products SELECT ROW_NUMBER()...
```

Everything works fine, but when I have a product with a single or double quotation marks in it's name, it doesn't show up in the results. SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF. When I remove the quotation marks it works, but when I add them again it doesn't show up.

What's my solution here?

Comment: Where/How are you viewing the results? Have you tried in SSMS?

Comment: How are you passing in the value of Product? Is it also a variable or are you building the Insert Statement dynamically? I think providing a more complete table schema and example query would help in answering your question.

Comment: Can you please post more information about what your stored procedure is doing (actual code)?  What we have now doesn't give us enough information to identify the issue.  Once we have this information, we can work with you to get it resolved so we can close out this question in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: Are you using full text on any of your columns? If so, you could review your accent sensitivity settings.

Answer (score 1):

Is your proc calling an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx) by any chance?

Indexed Views depend on SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER being set to ON. The proc will backfire in the case they are used explicitly using WITH (NOEXPAND), otherwise it can also grind down to a halt since it'll treat it as a normal view. See the following [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175088.aspx).

> Stored procedures and triggers should
>   be written to work with the six SET
>   options that are required to support
>   the indexes on views and computed
>   columns. The query optimizer does not
>   use an index on a view or computed
>   column in SELECT statements that are
>   executed by a stored procedure or
>   trigger when the SET options are
>   incorrectly set. An INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement in the stored
>   procedure or trigger that modifies
>   data values stored in the indexed view
>   or computed column generates an error.